# How can i say that every subspace is range space or null space of some linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example $V=\{(x+y+z,x+y-z):(x,y,z)∈\Bbb R^3\}$ is a range space of some linear transformation.
$V=\{(x,y,z)\colon x+y=0\}$, is a null space
of some linear transformation.
But what is gernal theorem? How can i say its true?
Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with projections?

Comment: yes some of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are working in $\mathbb R^{n}$. Given any subspace $M$ consider the orthogonal projection $P$ on $M$. Then $M$ is range of $P$ and the kernel of $I-P$.

[If $x \in M$ then projection of $x$ on $M$  is $x$ itself so $(I-P)x=x-Px=x-x=0$. Of course the projection of any vecotor lies in $M$ so the range of $P$ is $M$].